# Representation of a quadtree string

Tags: algorithm, haskell, tree, depth-first-search, quadtree

I am given a string in this form *ppeeefpffeefe*.
Values:

- *p* represents parent node
- *e* represents empty node
- *f* represents a full node

Image that represents this string can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZppc.png

I am writing code in Haskell and trying to convert this representation into 1024 long list of integers where 1 represents the black (full) pixel and 0 represents white (empty) pixel assuming the image size is 32x32 pixels.

This is the code I have but Haskell is giving me trouble. I know that I need to keep track of how many parent nodes I have visited and update highest level that way. I am trying to take DFS approach but anything that will do a job will help.

```
getQuad :: String -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
getQuad tree level highestLevel pCount result | (node == 'p') = result ++ (getQuad (drop 1 tree) (level+1) level 0 result)
                                              | (node == 'e')  = result ++ (getQuad (drop 1 tree) level highestLevel pCount (result ++ (take (getAmount level) [0,0..])))
                                              | (node == 'f') = result ++ (getQuad (drop 1 tree) level highestLevel pCount (result ++ (take (getAmount level) [1,1..])))
                                              | otherwise = result
                                               where
                                                    node = g

getNodeValue :: String -> Char
getNodeValue tree = if (length tree > 0) then tree !! 0 else 'x'

getAmount :: Int -> Int
getAmount l = 1024 `div` (4^l)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of "trouble" is Haskell giving you exactly? Please provide the full error message. If we don't see the error, we can't diagnose it.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin When I say trouble I mean I am not sure how to implement it. This algorithm fails when I give it a string that represents a tree with nested parent nodes. eg peepfeeefe

Comment: You might also want to explain what result the program gives and what result you expected and why there's a mismatch. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What's the purpose of `pcount`? You don't do anything with it, other than pass it (or 0) on to the recursive call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're trying to do way too much in a single function. I recommend starting over, and explicitly introducing separate parsing phases (to convert your `String` to an ADT representing it) and production phases (to convert a value of the ADT to a list of `Int`s). For example, a suitable ADT might look like this:

```
data QuadTree = Parent QuadTree QuadTree QuadTree QuadTree
              | Empty
              | Full
              deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
```

There are various techniques and libraries for parsing. Given your apparent level of expertise, and the simplicity of the format, I think I might recommend starting by writing the parser by hand and ignoring error-handling. Later you could think about learning about error-handling tools like `Maybe` or `Either` and parsing combinator libraries like `parsec` and friends to make it more flexible to changes in the language.

So, by hand and ignoring error-handling. Here's the skeleton I would put in place and try to fill out. Our parser needs to not just consume a `String`, but also be able to consume just part of a `String` and say what's left over: when handling a nested parent node, we need to return to the outer parent the chunk of the string that the inner parent didn't consume. So:

```
parseQuadTree :: String -> (String, QuadTree)
parseQuadTree ('p':rest) = -- TODO: exercise for the reader
parseQuadTree ('e':rest) = (rest, Empty)
parseQuadTree ('f':rest) = (rest, Full)
parseQuadTree other = error $ "parsing failed, expected a p, e, or f, but got " ++ other ++ " instead"
```

For example, we might expect the following ghci exchanges once we'd finished this function:

```
> parseQuadTree "e"
("", Empty)
> parseQuadTree "eef"
("ef", Empty)
> parseQuadTree "peeeeef"
("ef", QuadTree Empty Empty Empty Empty)
```

Once you have that, then I'd try to cook up a sensible representation of the 2d result. Perhaps a nested list would do:

```
type Image = [[Int]]
```

For example, you might interpret each element of the outer list as a row of the image; its elements are the columns of that row. The three basic operations you need for this thing are pasting images side-by-side horizontally and vertically and creating a blank image.

```
hcat, vcat :: Image -> Image -> Image
hcat = -- TODO: exercise for the reader
vcat = -- TODO: exercise for the reader

blank :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Image
blank w h pixel = -- TODO: exercise for the reader
-- OR, you could take just one size argument; we only ever need
-- square blank images in the following code
```

For example, you might expect these ghci exchanges once we'd finished implementing them:

```
> :set +m
> let x = [[0, 1]
|         ,[2, 3]
|         ]
|     y = [[4, 5]
|         ,[6, 7]
|         ]
|
> hcat x y
[[0,1,4,5],[2,3,6,7]]
> vcat x y
[[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]]
> blank 2 3 4
[[4,4],[4,4],[4,4]]
```

Now you can write a function which converts a `QuadTree` to an `Image`. We'll have to know how big the image is supposed to be, so let's make that an argument to the function.

```
renderQuadTree :: Int -> QuadTree -> Image
renderQuadTree size (Parent nw ne sw se) = -- TODO: exercise for the reader; use hcat and vcat
    where subtreeSize = size `div` 2
renderQuadTree size Empty = blank size size 0
renderQuadTree size Full = blank size size 1
```

For example, we might expect some such exchanges at ghci once this is finished:

```
> renderQuadTree 2 Empty
[[0,0],[0,0]]
> renderQuadTree 2 Full
[[1,1],[1,1]]
> renderQuadTree 2 (Parent Empty Full Full Empty)
[[0,1],[1,0]]
> renderQuadTree 4 (Parent Empty (Parent Full Empty Empty Full) Empty Full)
[[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1]]
```

Finally we could make a top-level function that combines all these into one convenient piece.

```
getQuad :: String -> [Int]
getQuad s = case parseQuadTree s of
    ("", t) -> concat (renderQuadTree 32 t)
    (s', _) -> error $ "parser did not consume the entire description string, leftovers are: " ++ s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer mate, it all makes sense and as you said I should probably try to do it step by step instead of trying to do everything in the same function. However I am confused in parsing the string where 'p' (parent node) is nested. How would I implement nested parent node in parseQuadTree function?

Comment: @zoric_l In English: call `parseQuadTree` recursively to parse a prefix of `rest`. It will return a `QuadTree` and a suffix. The `QuadTree` it returns is the first child; the suffix can be used in the same way to get the next child and an even shorter suffix, which can be used to get the next child and an even shorter suffix, which can be used to get the last child and the unparsed part to return.